# without refresh page show notification admin

Tags: php

On receiving notification members  are  required to click it.Then that notification  will erase form his notification board.but  it will be available  to other members who haven't viewed it yet.

Comment: you can use jquery ajax for that.

Comment: do you have code

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52404102/6309457

Comment: Hello @SaifIdrisi please see [How to ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide us some information what you want to, what happens and what you expect to happen.