# How to call a php functions using ajax and case

Tags: php, ajax

I have two php files one is index.php and other is phpscriptname.php. i need to call differet functions by using ajax and case method. i found a solution in a website which i give below, but this is not working.

index.php as below

```
<script>

$.ajax({ url: 'phpscriptname.php',
         data: {function2call: 'getEmployeesList'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      alert(output);
         }
});
</script>
```

phpscriptname.php as below

```
<?php?
if(isset($_POST['function2call']) && !empty($_POST['function2call'])) {
    $function2call = $_POST['function2call'];
    switch($function2call) {
        case 'getEmployeesList' : getEmployeesList();break;

    }
}


function getEmployeesList(){

    return "hai";
}


?>
```

i was expected "hai" in a popup. but it is not working.

Comment: you should `echo` instead of `return` to get value in `ajax`. so just replace  `return "hai";` by  `echo "hai";` Or if you want to return multiple data then refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52404102/6309457

Comment: Dear devsi odedra, i tried echo, but it is not working, can you please check from your side, Thanks in advance!

Comment: debug your switch case and see in console that what you passed what response you got

Comment: dear debung, thanks, it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert(output);` will not return anything becuase you are using `return` for getting plain text response from PHP, you need to use `echo` instead `return` in your method.

Second solution is that, if you want to use `return` in your method then you can modify your switch case as:

```
if(isset($_POST['function2call']) && !empty($_POST['function2call'])) {
    $data = ''; // initialize in default 
    $function2call = $_POST['function2call'];
    switch($function2call) {
        case 'getEmployeesList': 
        $data = getEmployeesList();
        break;
    }
    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: dear devpro, thanks for your supprot, it is solved!

Comment: @SABITH: glad to help u