# Cannot read the Ajax response returned by PHP file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, ajaxform

I am a newbie in Ajax.

I cannot get the correct response from PHP file. The answer in console is "Undefined". When I just address simply to the **Response** variable, the console gives me the Object; it seems that I cannot grab the value of the PHP file result.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return send_form(this)">
        <p>Number 1= <input type="text" name="number1"></p>
        <p>Number 2= <input type="text" name="number2"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="calculate">

    </form>
        <script>
           function send_form(form1){
                    let response=$.ajax("1_1.php",{
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:{n1:form1.number1.value, n2:form1.number2.value},
                    }
                    );
                console.log(response.c);

                return false;
            }

        </script>
```

and this is my PHP file

```
<?php

$a=$_GET['n1'];
$b=$_GET['n2'];
$c=$a+$b;

echo json_encode(['c'=>$c]);

?>
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52404102/6309457

Comment: The best advice I have: use the developer tools. In the Network panel, you can clearly see what the browser is sending and how the server is responding; use this information to see how exactly your code is failing.

Comment: This is the response from PHP file: {"c":38}.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, I have watched your link, but my response from PHP is actually already sent as an array with 1 element

Comment: @Azamat use success: of ajax, see my ajax code from link

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, Thank you. You gave me the right direction and I found out from your example that it's not a way to assign ajax to a variable. I tried with the method **then()**

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I shouldn't have used the assignment of **ajax** to a variable. I tried this way and it worked :

```
function send_form(form1){
                    $.ajax("1_1.php",{
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:{n1:form1.number1.value, n2:form1.number2.value},
                    }
                    ).then(process);

                return false;
            }
            function process(result){
                console.log(result.c);
                return false;
            }
```